# Dpdk pmd device not stopping

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

I am using memif devices in my project. As you know memif's are the eth devices in dpdk. When I am ending my application, I am stopping, disable promiscuous mode and closing memif eth devices. This is the sequence I fallow;

```
rte_eth_dev_stop(portId);
rte_eth_promiscuous_disable(portId);
rte_eth_dev_close(portId);
```

Eth device gives error Unknown error -95 (-95) in rte_eth_dev_stop(portId) and same error no at rte_eth_promiscuous_disable() function. Besides I get the memif_disconnect(): Failed to unregister control channel callback error. But rte_eth_dev_close() return success. I don't know what am I doing wrong ? Maybe the closing sequence could be wrong.

I would be very appreciated if you guide me about that issue. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mustafa I request to spend some time in both documentation and code, which will help in easily understanding that **memif does not enable or disable promiscuous mode**.

Let me explain

1. From DPDK [NIC overview][1] `Table 1.1 Features availability in networking drivers` it calls out various features what is supported
2. For memif promsicous mode is not present.
3. DPDK internal library (rte_ethdev) implements `promiscuous_enable and promiscuous_disable` to support user requests to be transferred to underlying PMD.
4. In case of memif, check [code][2] code `static const struct eth_dev_ops ops`. The promiscuous enable|dsiable function handlers are absent.

Hence there is nothing wrong memif.

[EDIT-1] with respect to memif `rte_eth_dev_stop`, checking for memif_dev_stop, only the return value is `return 0;` hence the claim of  `-95` for stop device is not valid.

Note: please check the code and links to better understand the code.
[1]: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html
[2]: https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/memif/rte_eth_memif.c

Comment: thank you again. But I still could not get rid of stop error. Somehow I get that error and error does not give any useful output with rte_strerror. I am feeling I should flush the rx and tx buffer or something else. I dont know :(

Comment: @Mustafa your question was on `rte_eth_promiscuous_disable` the answer address the same. Please accept and upvote to close the question. If you have question on stop, please open a new ticket. it is stack overflow model to focus on one question at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked at the links and that was very helpful. Maybe I made a mistake by not mentioning about dpdk version. I am using 20.11.1 version. So, I checked the rte_eth_memif.c file and I could not find memif_dev_stop function in that version. In that version, ***rte_eth_dev_stop()*** is available and I am using it. So all the cases are solved I think. Thank you again....